# $wpdb sql help. Select post id and post meta value based on 2 other post_meta values

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to select post ids and a post meta value based on the value of 2 other post meta values and from a custom post type.

Here is a screen shot of my post meta table.
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s40/sh/99a4c115-48bb-46c4-81ef-0df3ccd48862/3f9e2d56e7bb5db54a64782b9860ab4b/deep/0/wp_13_postmeta%20@local_wp_multisite_%20(localhost).png

I need the `_days` meta_key value based on the values of the `_start_date` and `_end_date` values.

I also would like to return the post id's.

UPDATE:
I think I got it. It is not in wordpress form but that is the easy part. If anyone can improve on this please add to it. Thanks

```
 SELECT
key1.ID,
key1.post_title,
days.meta_value AS days
FROM
wp_13_posts key1
INNER JOIN wp_13_postmeta days ON days.post_id = key1.ID
AND days.meta_key = '_days'
INNER JOIN wp_13_postmeta startdate ON startdate.post_id = key1.ID
AND startdate.meta_key = '_start_date'
INNER JOIN wp_13_postmeta enddate ON enddate.post_id = key1.ID
AND enddate.meta_key = '_end_date'
WHERE
days.meta_key = '_days'
AND startdate.meta_value <= '1385769600'
AND enddate.meta_value >= '1383264000'
AND key1.post_type = 'mbe_enrollments'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $post_this_month = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT
    key1.ID,
    key1.post_title,
    days.meta_value as days
    FROM
    $wpdb->posts key1
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta days ON days.post_id = key1.ID
    AND days.meta_key = %s
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta startdate ON startdate.post_id = key1.ID
    AND startdate.meta_key = %s
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta enddate ON enddate.post_id = key1.ID
    AND enddate.meta_key = %s

    WHERE days.meta_key = %s
     AND startdate.meta_value <= %s
     AND enddate.meta_value >= %s
     AND key1.post_type = %s
      ", '_days', '_start_date', '_end_date',
    '_days', $month_end, $month_start, 'mbe_enrollments'
    ));
```